How to change the cursor to the Apple 'busy' cursor before calling a function using SwiftUI
I'm attempting to learn Swift/SwiftUI and have written a small test app to learn some techniques.  I have a couple of Swift functions that are called back to back in the Action of a button that could take some time to complete as they import over 4,000 files that contain binary data.
I would like to change the cursor to display the system 'busy' cursor while the functions run.  I've spent several hours looking for solutions but have not found any solutions such as looking at all the cursor types that are in NSCursor.
Here's a code snippet from a view.  BTW the variable images do not refer to formatted images such as PNG.
    Button(action: {  // this could take a little time.
        NSCursor.closedHand.push() // Want 'busy' or 'wait' cursor here
    images = getImageList(folder)
    importImages(images)
    NSCursor.pop()
    }) {
        Text("Import Images")
    }


Does this answer your question? SwiftUI System Cursor

If you're blocking the main (UI) thread of your application, that's a sign you should be using one of the asynchronous techniques available to you. Current machines have lots of cores, and you might as well take advantage of them. Modern code uses async/await, but dispatch queues would be another way to spread your import among many cores.
NSProgressReporting is the protocol your import task should conform to.
There's another red flag in your code. Your View appears to be managing the import. That's not the way SwiftUI is meant to work, because SwiftUI is a declarative framework. Instead, your button should tell another object (perhaps the View Model) to begin the import. Your View will lay things out depending on the import status of the View Model or Data Importer. If state == .imported, show the UI to trigger the import. If state == .inProgress, show an NSProgressIndicator (based on NSProgress or another NSProgressReporting implementation) or a spinning indeterminate busy indicator. If state == .finished, show the imported images. But all of the logic for importing and processing your images happens off the main thread, and not on any object that knows anything about SwiftUI.
If the system shows the user a beach ball, that's a bad experience.

Well at least I now know that my model does import my data correctly.  I'll re-write the code so that loop occurs in the model and follow the links that you kindly provided.
